# Swift- UI Progress Bar not showing up

Tags: swift, position, sprite-kit, cgpoint

Here's what I have so far in my `didMoveToView()` function:

```
backgroundLayer.zPosition = -1
hudLayer.zPosition = 100

addChild(backgroundLayer)
addChild(hudLayer)
backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

let healthBar: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Healthbar")
healthBar.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
healthBar.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1.0)
hudLayer.addChild(healthBar)
```

My background shows up fine, and I have both a `backgroundLayer` and a `hudLayer`. I even made the zposition much higher for the `hudLayer` to make sure it's in front. As for the positioning, I think I have the anchor point to be at the top-left of the sprite, and tried various ways to position it- it seems to only show up when I use something like:

```
healthBar.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.width/2)
```

My question is why? `size.width/2` isn't working for when I test on different screen sizes (on an iphone4, the health bar is further down).

Doesn't size take the current size of the screen? I thought using size would make it somewhat 'responsive' but I can't get the behavior to work right. Therefore, I thought maybe the `CGPoint` coordinate system `(0-1.0)` would work better, but it's not showing up at all with that.

Thanks for reading, I don't understand why it won't show up :(

Comment: Your scene is not necessarily the same size as your screen

Comment: So I got the maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(screenSize.height) and plugged it into the y-position of my health bar, and it shows up near the bottom of the  screen. Which is weird..I'm not sure why it wouldn't show up at the top.